# Product: You can't view this item in Lightning Experience (Salesforce1 / Mobile)

Tags: lightning, javascript, salesforce1-app, mobile

I have a custom list of Products which appear in Salesforce in both mobile and desktop.

When the user clicks on the button in the list:

```
<lightning:button label="{!r.Name}" value="{!r.Id}" onclick="{! c.navigateToProduct }" variant="base" />
```

It calls this JavaScript controller method:

```
navigateToProduct: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    let recordId = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvent.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId,
        "slideDevName": "related"
    });
    navEvent.fire();
}
```

But when clicked from mobile (Salesforce1 or web) the Product page fails to load:

[image]

But when I try from a desktop computer it loads fine.

---

I have also tried using a plain anchor tag, which did not work:

```
<a href="{!r.url}">{!r.Name}</a>
```

And I've tried using `window.location.href`, which did not work.

---

What am I doing wrong?
How can I link to a product in a way that works on mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that it is not possible to view a Product record via mobile or Salesforce1

There is a Salesforce Idea: [Allow Products / Pricebooks to be displayed in Salesforce1 app](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxxfAAA)